# matlab: how to transform screen pixels into specific coordinates

Tags: matlab, coordinates, axis, pixel

I have to draw a curve captured on a image using screen pixels (mouse clicks) into a coordinate system. E.g.: Pixels on the screen, from left to right (130 px to 970 px) correspond to the x-axis of my coordinate system (1000 to 6000). Pixels from bottom to top (670 to 99) correspond to the y-axis of coordinate system (0 to 1.2). How can this be done? Maybe there's a function in matlab doing something like that?

Some more explanation:
I have a jpg image of a curve on a coordinate system. I've got pixel positions (x,y) of several points on that curve. Now I want to plot same curve into a matlab figure with same x and y axis as on the jpg image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a MATLAB function/command to do this, but it may not be too difficult to come up with something.

Suppose that `xPixDiff = 970-130` and `xAxisDiff = 6000-1000`.  Then the `xPixel` value from any `(xPixel,yPixel)` pair can be translated into an x-axis coordinate via

```
xAxisCoord = (xPixel-130)*xAxisDiff/xPixDiff + 1000
```

It is clear from the above that `xPixel=130` maps to `1000` and `xPixel=970` maps to `6000`.

The `yAxisCoord` calculation is similar but we just have to remember that the "directions" are opposite in the y-axis coordinate system and the y pixel positions.

Let `yPixDiff=99-670` and `yAxisDiff=1.2-0`.  Then the `yPixel` value from any `(xPixel,yPixel)` pair can be translated into an y-axis coordinate via

```
yAxisCoord = (yPixel-670)*yAxisDiff/yPixDiff + 0
```

It is clear from the above that `yPixel=670` maps to `0` and `yPixel=99` maps to `1.2`.

Hope that the above helps!